# For blazor wasm hosted, with Azure ad b2c, why I must to refresh the page to stop getting a 401

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, webassembly

I'm trying to configure blazor wasm hosted with azure AD B2C. I can connect with my account but when i try to call API in server project, I get a 401 http result.

I followed this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0

If I refresh the page several times, I get a 200 http result and the content is ok.

I don't understand why I must refresh the page. Do you have an idea of ​​the problem?

I tried all the docs I found on the internet that deal with this problem. however, my context is a bit different from what I find because in my case it works after multiple page refreshes

Comment: I think I found the problem, WWW-authentication in my api call contains the following message: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token is not valid before '07/15/2023 19:04:11'"

Is it possible to change the value of "nbf" (Not Before) in the token ?

Comment: or an other solution ?

Comment: In addition, my application work on azure, this problem is only on locahost.

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD SPA Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

The error "401" usually occurs if the access token doesn't have sufficient permissions to perform the action.

In your scenario, the 401 error is because access token is expired.

**To resolve the error,** try the below:

- You can increase the access token lifetime.
- Or generate the refresh token and refresh the access token.

**To increase the token lifetime,**

*Go to Azure AD B2C -> User Flows -> Select your User flow -> Properties -> Save*

[image]

Otherwise, you can also make use of below **PowerShell script** to increase the token lifetime:

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId TenantID -Scopes "Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework"

$params = @{  
Definition = @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"23:59:59"}}')  
DisplayName = "WebPolicyScenario"  
IsOrganizationDefault = $false  
}  
$tokenLifetimePolicyId=(New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -BodyParameter $params).Id
```

I generated **tokens** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://rukkb2c.b2clogin.com/rukkb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testrukpolicy/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://rukkb2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientId/access_as_user offline_access openid
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Otherwise, to generate the **refresh token** modify like below:

```json
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://tenant.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "ClientID",
    "Domain": "Domain",
    "Scopes": "https://rukkb2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientId/access_as_user offline_access  ",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "Policy"
}
```

```cs
var rToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");
```

This will generate refresh token and by using this you can refresh the access token which will resolve the error. Use **`AccessTokenResult.InteractionOptions`** to refresh the access token.

**Reference:**

[Secure a hosted ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly app with Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0#fetchdata-component)

Comment: Tanks for help, token not expired but not valid yet. i resolved with synchronisation my pc on Time.Windows.com for localhost.